# Is this the correct syntax for 'array_unique()' in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to get rid of duplicates in my array but I'm still printing duplicates with this:

```
$getuser = ltrim($top10['url'], " users/" );  //trim url to get user id
$array[$i++] = $getuser; 
$dirty = $array;
$clean = array_unique($dirty);
print_r($clean)."<br />";
```

Input `print_r($array)`

```
Array ( [0] => 33 [1] => 3 [2] => 29 [3] => 3104 ) Array ( [0] => 156686 [1] => 5 [2] => 3104 [3] => 1 ) Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 115023 [2] => 185367 [3] => 180694 ) Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 5 [2] => 3104 [3] => 139403 ) Array ( [0] => 3110 [1] => 2723 [2] => 8087 [3] => 97410 ) Array ( [0] => 1925 [1] => 60 [2] => 18995 [3] => 2940 ) Array ( [0] => 103205 [1] => 111503 [2] => 2 [3] => 128715 ) Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 119266 [2] => 4 [3] => 3104 ) Array ( [0] => 32565 [1] => 2743 [2] => 148584 [3] => 3505 ) Array ( [0] => 35282 [1] => 99136 [2] => 54167 [3] => 5326 )
```

Output `print_r($clean)`;

```
Array ( [0] => 33 [1] => 3 [2] => 29 [3] => 3104 ) Array ( [0] => 156686 [1] => 5 [2] => 3104 [3] => 1 ) Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 115023 [2] => 185367 [3] => 180694 ) Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 5 [2] => 3104 [3] => 139403 ) Array ( [0] => 3110 [1] => 2723 [2] => 8087 [3] => 97410 ) Array ( [0] => 1925 [1] => 60 [2] => 18995 [3] => 2940 ) Array ( [0] => 103205 [1] => 111503 [2] => 2 [3] => 128715 ) Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 119266 [2] => 4 [3] => 3104 ) Array ( [0] => 32565 [1] => 2743 [2] => 148584 [3] => 3505 ) Array ( [0] => 35282 [1] => 99136 [2] => 54167 [3] => 5326 )
```

Comment: The second parameter to `ltrim` doesn't do what I think you intend it to do. It is interpreted as a charlist, not a complete string.

Comment: I've tried $getuser = substr($top10['url'],7) but it leaves 7 null chars. The trim() function I use works fine. My problem is that I am still getting duplicates.

Comment: Can you post an example of your input and output?  If you have null characters happening, they are probably interfering with the comparisons that `array_unique` is doing to determine if two values are duplicates.

Comment: By using trim() I have no more null characters. The string sizes are the same when I do a var_dump.

Comment: Your code looks like it is being executed in a loop, given the counter. Are you showing us multiple, separate inputs and outputs, or is that the input/output in one go? In any case, there are no duplicates in any of the output arrays. I think you may have a logical error.

Comment: Hmm, I think I figured it out. I'm filling multiple arrays with the loop instead of just one. Oops, Thanks @erisco!

Comment: patrick, it would be beneficial to stackoverflow to fill out your own answer as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems to be correct. Basically you specify an array to `array_unique` and it gives you unique items out of the array.

```
$unique_array = array_unique($your_array);
```